# ANTLR behaviour with conflicting tokens

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

How is ANTLR lexer behavior defined in the case of conflicting tokens?
Let me explain what I mean by "conflicting" tokens.
For example, assume that the following is defined:

```
INT_STAGE       :   '1'..'6';
INT             :   '0'..'9'+;
```

There is a conflict here, because after reading a sequence of digits, the lexer would not know whether there is one INT or many INT_STAGE tokens (or different combinations of both).
After a test, it looks like that if INT is defined after INT_STAGE, the lexer would prefer to find INT_STAGE, but maybe not INT then? Otherwise, no INT_STAGE  would ever be found.

Another example would be:

```
FOOL: ' fool'
FOO: 'foo'
ID              :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'%') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'%')*;
```

I was told that this is the "right" order to recognize all the tokens:
while reading "fool" the lexer will find one FOOL token and not FOO ID or something else.

Answer (score 2):

The following logic applies:

1. the lexer matches as much characters as possible
2. if after applying rule 1, there are 2 or more rules that match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will "win"

Taking this into account, the input `"1"`, `"2"`, ..., `"6"` is tokenized as an `INT_STAGE`: both `INT_STAGE` and `INT` match the same amount of characters, but `INT_STAGE` is defined first.

The input `"12"` is tokenized as a `INT` since it matches the most characters.

> I was told that this is the "right" order to recognize all the tokens: while reading "fool" the lexer will find one FOOL token and not FOO ID or something else.

That is correct.

Comment: I have another problem - why 
TEST_TOKEN      : 'Stage' ('1'..'6');
ID              :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'%') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'%')*;
is not working - no TEST_TOKEN are found ?

Comment: @user1607242, feel free to ask a new question then. These comment boxes are ill suited for Q&A's.