# Parsing letter ranges with ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following parser rules:

```
defDirective : defType whiteSpace letterSpec (whiteSpace? COMMA whiteSpace? letterSpec)*;
defType :
        DEFBOOL | DEFBYTE | DEFINT | DEFLNG | DEFLNGLNG | DEFLNGPTR | DEFCUR |
        DEFSNG | DEFDBL | DEFDATE | 
        DEFSTR | DEFOBJ | DEFVAR
;
letterSpec : universalLetterRange | letterRange | singleLetter;

singleLetter : RESTRICTED_LETTER;
universalLetterRange : upperCaseA whiteSpace? MINUS whiteSpace? upperCaseZ;
upperCaseA : {_input.Lt(1).Text.Equals("A")}? RESTRICTED_LETTER;
upperCaseZ : {_input.Lt(1).Text.Equals("Z")}? RESTRICTED_LETTER;
letterRange : firstLetter whiteSpace? MINUS whiteSpace? lastLetter;
firstLetter : RESTRICTED_LETTER;
lastLetter : RESTRICTED_LETTER;

whiteSpace : (WS | LINE_CONTINUATION)+;
```

with the relevant Lexer Rules:

```
RESTRICTED_LETTER : [a-zA-Z];
MINUS : '-';
COMMA : ',';
WS : [ \t];
LINE_CONTINUATION : [ \t]* UNDERSCORE [ \t]* '\r'? '\n';
```

and the DefTypes matching their camel-case spelling.

Now when I try to test this on the following inputs, it works exactly as expected:

```
DefInt I,J,K
DefBool A-Z
```

It does **not** work however on arbitary letter ranges (see rule `letterRange`). When I use the input `DefByte B-F`, I get the error message "line 1:8 mismatched input 'B' expecting RESTRICTED_LETTER"

I've tried expressing `RESTRICTED_IDENTIFIER` as a range (`'A'..'Z'|'a'..'z'`), but that didn't change anything about the error message.

When changing the first `whiteSpace` in `defDirective` to `whiteSpace+` the error message gets a little longer (now including WS and LINE_CONTINUATION in the expected alternatives).

Also the parse-tree generated by the IntelliJ ANTLR Plugin suddenly starts recognizing the `F` as a `singleLetter`, which it previously didn't.

This behaviour seems to be consistent between targetlanguages Java and CSharp.

Previously the rule used to be a lot more relaxed, but that led to incorrect parse-trees, so I kinda want to fix this.

How can I correctly recognize `letterRange` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ... @BartKiers had the right suspicion. The given Lexer rules weren't all the rules involved in the process.

The full grammar contains a lexer rule `B_CHAR : B` that's used in a special case of an unrelated grammar rule. That `B_CHAR` took precedence over `RESTRICTED_LETTER` when lexing the input stream.

The grammar rules presented are correct (and work fine), but the `B_CHAR` token needs to be removed from the Tokens lexed.

Comment: Good to see you solved it. FYI, this is how ANTLR determines what lever rule to choose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592107/antlr-behaviour-with-conflicting-tokens